# Unreadable content error encountered when exporting .xlsm file

Tags: c#

Spreadsheet displays warning message when trying to export .xlsm file.

Export Button Code:

```
    var binData = new byte[filename.PostedFile.ContentLength];

    filename.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(binData, 0, filename.PostedFile.ContentLength);

    filename.PostedFile.InputStream.Close();

    Stream st = new MemoryStream(binData); 

    Download excel = new Download();

    byte[] result = excel.Generate(list, st, code); 

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;  filename={0}", filename.FileName));

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12";

    Response.BinaryWrite(result);
```

Comment: Save the generated file and open it in a text editor (eg Notepad++) and paste the results in your question

Comment: Also what is the Download class? If it's your own class you may need to paste it in your question so we can understand what it does